# In Weka, how can I use GridSearch to fine tune 5 algorithms?

Tags: weka, fine-tuning

In Weka, I want to apply 5 algorithms (NB, SVM, LR, KNN, and RF). Further, I want to fine-tune their parameters by using GridSearch.

My question is: How can I know the values of their parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [GridSearch](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/gridSearch/index.html) package, I recommend using [MultiSearch](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/multisearch/index.html) instead.

The latter allows you to optimize not just two parameters, but also a single one or more than two. Of course, the more parameters (and individual parameter values) you want to explore, the larger the search space and the longer the evaluation will take.

Furthermore, it also supports non-numeric parameters (eg `boolean` - use `ListParameter` in that case instead of `MathParameter`).

In terms of what parameters to optimize, you have to look through the parameters in the Weka GUI, e.g., the Weka Explorer, and make a decision.

When you click on a classifier's panel, you bring up its options in the GenericObjectEditor. When clicking on the **More** button in that dialog, you can view the description of the available options.

E.g., the options for **NaiveBayes** are as follows:

```
OPTIONS
useKernelEstimator -- Use a kernel estimator for numeric attributes rather than a normal distribution.

numDecimalPlaces -- The number of decimal places to be used for the output of numbers in the model.

batchSize -- The preferred number of instances to process if batch prediction is being performed. More or fewer instances may be provided, but this gives implementations a chance to specify a preferred batch size.

debug -- If set to true, classifier may output additional info to the console.

displayModelInOldFormat -- Use old format for model output. The old format is better when there are many class values. The new format is better when there are fewer classes and many attributes.

doNotCheckCapabilities -- If set, classifier capabilities are not checked before classifier is built (Use with caution to reduce runtime).

useSupervisedDiscretization -- Use supervised discretization to convert numeric attributes to nominal ones.
```

Only `useKernelEstimator` and `useSupervisedDiscretization` will influence the model, all other options only influence the display of the model or output debugging information.

These names (aka properties) you can then use in MultiSearch to reference the options that you want to evaluate.

E.g., here are the two `ListParameter` setups for **NaiveBayes** that will make up the search space:

```
weka.core.setupgenerator.ListParameter -property useKernelEstimator -list "false true"
weka.core.setupgenerator.ListParameter -property useSupervisedDiscretization -list "false true"
```

However, since these two parameters cannot be used in conjunction, you will have to wrap each in a `ParameterGroup` object to have them explored separately:

```
weka.core.setupgenerator.ParameterGroup -search "weka.core.setupgenerator.ListParameter -property useSupervisedDiscretization -list \"false true\""
weka.core.setupgenerator.ParameterGroup -search "weka.core.setupgenerator.ListParameter -property useKernelEstimator -list \"false true\""
```

The best setup (as a command-line) will be output with the classifier model, e.g.:

```
weka.classifiers.meta.MultiSearch:
Classifier: weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -K
```